# Finding approximate answer of a square term

Tags: binomial-theorem

I am given $ m<<M $. I have to find approximate value of $(\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{M}}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}})^2$

My book does it as follows:

$
(\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{M}}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}})^2 =  (\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}}\sqrt{1+\frac{m}{M}}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}})^2     \tag{1}
$

$
= \frac{1}{m}(\sqrt{1+\frac{m}{M}}-1)^2      \tag{2}
$

$
=\frac{1}{m}(1+\frac{m}{2M}-1)^2    \tag{3}
$

$
=\frac{m}{4M^2}    \tag{4}
$

I understand this procedure. But i tried to do it differently:

$
(\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{M}}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}})^2 =  (\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{M}})^2 + (\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}})^2 - 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{M}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}}   \tag{5}
$

$
=\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{M}+\frac{1}{m}-2\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}}\sqrt{1+\frac{m}{M}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}}       \tag{6}
$

$
=\frac{2}{m}+\frac{1}{M}-2\frac{1}{m}\sqrt{1+\frac{m}{M}}      \tag{7}
$

$
=\frac{2}{m}+\frac{1}{M}-2\frac{1}{m}(1+\frac{m}{2M})         \tag{8}
$

$
=\frac{2}{m}+\frac{1}{M}-\frac{2}{m}-\frac{2m}{2Mm}      \tag{9}
$

$
=\frac{1}{M}-\frac{1}{M} = 0       \tag{10}
$

I am getting 0. Where did i make an error.

Comment: $\sqrt{1 + x} - 1 = x/2$ 
$\implies (\sqrt{1 + x} - 1)^2 = x^2/4$

But let's see what is happening if instead of first putting the approximated value, you square it first.

$(\sqrt{1 + x} - 1)^2 = 1 + x -2\sqrt{1+x} = 1+ x -2(1+ x/2) = (\sqrt{1+x})^2 -2(1+x/2)$

Notice the term $(\sqrt{1+x})^2$. When you are putting the approximated value after expanding the expression you are not putting that value for this term. That's why the difference in your answer and theirs.